# Elastic search " settings " add in Python module

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch

How the following settings can be add to python elastic search module. Please provide a example. I have created indexes and mappings. But I am stuck with settings.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/blurays " -d'
{
   "settings": {
     "analysis": {
     "filter": {
        "nGram_filter": {
           "type": "nGram",
           "min_gram": 2,
           "max_gram": 20,
           "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit",
              "punctuation",
              "symbol"
           ]
        }
     },
     "analyzer": {
        "nGram_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "whitespace",
           "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "nGram_filter"
           ]
        },
        "whitespace_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "whitespace",
           "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
           ]
        }
     }
  }
 },
```

Comment: What you want to do with this settings? You want to push this settings to index ?

Comment: @Lafada Yes man. I want these settings to be used at my index. I have to upload some documents with these settings and at the end I want to implement a auto complete suggester.

Comment: You want to do this using py-elasticsearch module ?

Comment: @Lafada - Exactly. using the py-elasticsearch module. Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`elasticsearch.indices.create`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create) and pass the settings as body.

Docs says:

**create(*args, **kwargs)**

Create an index in Elasticsearch. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Parameters:

- index – The name of the index
- body – The configuration for the index (settings and mappings)
- master_timeout – Specify timeout for connection to master
- timeout – Explicit operation timeout

So you can pass `body` with settings argument.

Answer (score 6):

If your index already exists, you can update its settings with [`elasticsearch.indices.put_settings`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_settings).